# Given a measure zero subset $N$ of $A- A$, can we find a measure zero $B\subseteq A$ such that $N \subseteq B-B$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given a subset $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we write as $C-C$ the set $\{x-y, x,y \in C\}$. Given a measure zero subset $N$ of $A-  A$, can we find measure zero set $B\subseteq A$ such that $N \subseteq B-B$. $A\subseteq\mathbb{R} $ and the measure is Lebesgue measure?

I need this to solve some other problem. Can someone help?

Comment: What do you mean by $A - A$?

Comment: $A-A=\{x-y: x,y\in A\}$

Comment: Yes, it has to be measure zero subset.